# What are the performance differences between 32 and 64 bits SWT?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

My team develops an Eclipse RCP application.  Should we expect any performance differences between a build using 32-bit SWT and a build using 64-bit SWT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, 32-bit and 64-bit java applications almost always have the same structure.

As I'm sure you already know, the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit is the amount of memory the application can hold. A 32-bit SWT will hold ~4GB of memory, while a 64-bit can hold +16GB (its much larger than this.).

If you find any differences, it will only be found at the back-end of SWT, or the native code.

Answer (score 4):

There shouldn't be any differences. Note that a 32 bit SWT/RCP will only run on a 32 bit JRE/JDK and 64 bit SWT/RCP will only run on a 64 bit JRE/JDK.

Other parts of the Eclipse RCP also have 32/64 bit versions, they must all be the same.

Also note that SWT and RCP are platform dependent so a Windows build won't run on Linux or OS X.

Comment: Don't Java programs run on any VM(32 or 64 bit), or is this a native C/C++ problem?

Comment: @LukeMelaia SWT is not just pure Java. It is platform-dependent. The answer to your question is it's a native problem.

Comment: @LukeMelaia Parts of SWT are coded in C. They are also dependent on the APIs for the different windowing systems - Win32 API, Cocoa on OS X, GTK on Linux/Unix. There are actually 15 variations for the various supported platforms.